# Unexpected different page sizes when merging PDF's in Java using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have the following code snippet to merge two single paged PDF files (first and second):

```
byte[] codes = IOUtils.toByteArray(resource.getURI());
PdfReader first = new PdfReader(firstBytes);
PdfReader second = new PdfReader(secondBytes);
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, byteArrayOutputStream);
document.open();
copy.addDocument(first);
copy.addDocument(second);
document.close();
return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
```

Next I have the following test:

```
byte[] generated = new Merger(...).generate(...); // Location of the snippet above
File file = new File("dir", "generated.pdf");
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file , generated);
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(file));
assertThat(pdfReader.getNumberOfPages()).isEqualTo(2);
```

This test works fine locally and fails on our build server.

Locally the generated PDF simply looks contains the two A4 pages On the build server there are three pages:

- the first document
- one blank page
- the second document

The first two pages seem to be in letter format, while the last page seems to be an A4 page.

How do I fix this?

Edit: Some extra info. Local OS is Windows. Build system runs Linux.

Comment: What is your local and build server system config (OS and other relevant details)?

Comment: Please share sample documents to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sadly I can't share the actual documents, added requested OS information. Both input PDF's are in A4 size.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Thus, the problem most likely is caused by something in the specific input documents of the tests on the build server. As you cannot share them, there is nothing we can do from here. (Alternatively the code failing on the build server is different from the code you run locally. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first generated document was generated using the [flying-saucer library](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer). It was fixed by [setting the page size in the css](http://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_35).

My assumption of where the problem was located was completely wrong. Sorry.